# Search products with name both "test product" and "test-product"

Tags: php, mysql, search

I have a search functionality in one of my cart with CS-Cart framework. I have products like "test products","test-products","test/products" and so on in some case.
I have used following query "descr1.search_words LIKE %.$query.%" to fetch all corresponding products with the query term.
Its showing only "test product" when i search for "test product".
But i need output as it showing all the product as mentioned above with the terms test and product.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you show us your actual code?

Comment: I am just used simple search query to fetch data with "LIKE"
 LIKE %.$query.%" here my $query="test product"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try replacing the space with the wildcard for the comparison:

```
where descr1.search_words like concat('%', replace($query, ' ', '%'), '%')
```

Of course, this will also find match with other words between the keywords.

Comment: Is it work if i search for "test-products" or "test/products" ?
In my database product name will be as "test product","test-product" etc.
The search should show all results if i search for "test-products" or "test products"